# Автоформатирование кода на Python (PEP8)

Tags: python, code-style

Ищу автоформатирование кода на Python 3.7, онлайн. Думал, залезу в гугл и сразу найду, но нет. Видимо в основном, существует 2 решения.

Первое как на [этом сайте](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_formatter.htm) выводит ошибки вместо исправления форматирования. Типа:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pythontidy", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PythonTidy==1.21', 'console_scripts', 'pythontidy')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/runner.py", line 31, in main
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/PythonTidy.py", line 4809, in tidy_up
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/compiler/transformer.py", line 51, in parse
    return Transformer().parsesuite(buf)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/compiler/transformer.py", line 128, in parsesuite
    return self.transform(parser.suite(text))
  File "<string>", line 71
    distance: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='Distance', default=0.01, min=0.0001, max=10.0, step=1)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Это здорово, конечно, что он находит, как он думает, ошибки в коде, но я же его не просил об этом.

[2й вариант](https://codebeautify.org/python-formatter-beautifier) уже лучше.
Он конечно вставляет отступы вокруг математических операторов но при этом убивает отступы! Зачем автоформатер, который делает код не рабочим, не известно.

Все остальные сайты, видимо, используют схожие алгоритмы.

Из этого вопрос, неужели нормального автоформатирования никто не придумал, или я упустил какой-то сайт?

Comment: Надо именно онлайн?

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, онлайн

Comment: `Это здорово, конечно, что он находит, как он думает, ошибки в коде, но я же его не просил об этом.` чтобы форматирование сделать нужно будет синтаксический анализ кода провести, а после имея токены вывести код в форматированном виде. А у вас код на питон3? Просто, судя по тексту ошибки на том сайте питон2 использовался, а у вас встретилась конструкция `distance: bpy.props.FloatProperty(`, что похоже на typing hint, который в python3 появился. Например, попробуйте на первом сайте это форматировать `a: int = 12`

Comment: @gil9red  python 3.7.0

Comment: Просто онлайн никому не нужно, а вот оффлайн навалом. И да, код с ошибками форматировать невозможно

Answer (score 2):

Есть отличная статья на хабре: https://habr.com/ru/post/251531/

Одно из решений:
autopep8

Ошибки стандарта часто повторяются от файла в файлу. И возникает сильное желание исправление автоматизировать. В этом случае на арену выходит autopep8.
Как и pep8, он умеет самостоятельно определять ошибки, а также исправлять их. Список исправляемых ошибок форматирования можно найти здесь
Само использование autopep8 крайне простое и может выглядеть так:

$ autopep8 ./ --recursive --in-place -a